# Are there any benefits to owning a Trump Card?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, fundraising

Trump-branded cards were given out to those who donated $45 to Trump’s PAC as part of a fundraising campaign.

Other than physically having the card, and being able to show it to others, are there any benefits to the card?

Does it entitle the holder to discount rates at one of his hotels? Earlier tee times at one of his golf courses? Anything at all, other than just owning a few cents worth of plastic?

---

[Update] as @F1Krazy commented, maybe this needs some links to explain what a Trump Card is:

- [There's now an official Trump Card design, and getting one will cost you $45](https://www.businessinsider.com/official-trump-card-design-getting-one-will-cost-45-2021-9)
- [The Secret Fundraising Magic of Trump Cards](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-08-05/trump-cards-the-story-behind-the-secret-fundraising-magic)
- it's possible that [Opinion: Your Trump Card benefits](https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2021/08/06/your-trump-card-benefits/) actually answers the question, although it is satirical

[image]

Comment: Closed as off topic? Any reason ("This question does not appear to be about governments, policies and political processes within the scope defined in the help center" - is fund raising off-topic)? I can't ask it on [skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) Any idea where I could ask this?

Comment: I think what this question is missing is context. I'd never heard of "Trump Cards" before reading this question. Having Googled it, it seems like Trump is selling these to (ostensibly) raise money for his political activities, which I *think* would make this on-topic, but you'd have to edit the question to include that context.

Comment: Please accept my apologies (+1).  I guess that I just assumed that everyone had heard of them.  I have edited the question to include a link - would you vote to re-open?

Comment: Essentially, *Are there **non-political** benefits to making campaign contributions to a particular (potential) candidate?* does not seem like a useful question for this site.

Comment: I’m inclined to say that this is on-topic as these cards were given to political donors. Giving out cards is actually a common fundraising tactic for political campaigns. Voted to re-open.

Comment: Not really sure how a fund raising item that a single candidate is selling is on topic for this site. Is this card really any different than any other physical item you can buy such as a hat or shirt? In fact I would say it is even less value since it is something you have to go out of your way to show someone.

Comment: @JoeW isn't that just what the question is asking? Is there any value to this beyond what you would get from a hat or t-shirt. Membership cards usually come with something attached, gym entry or hotel loyalty points. Why is a political campaign selling 'memberships'? Membership to what? Is the core of the question.

Comment: @Jontia I think you missed my point. If you can ask what is the value of owning a Trump card wouldn't you also want to know the benefit of owning a maga  hat or shirt? What about a bumper sticker? Or a yard sign? What is the benefit of owning any sort of political fund raising swag?

Comment: @JoeW I see the point you're making, but no I think there is a clear difference. The card has no practical purpose in and of itself, a hat can be worn a bumper sticker or yard sign is displayed. This card say you are a member. A member of what? What does membership entail in terms of on going costs and rewards? The answer can of course be nothing, in which case it isn't very different from those other items and that would be a great answer to the question. But all the membership cards I own do something else, does this?

Comment: @Joe W: Hats and t-shirts have an obvious functional value in themselves, while bumper stickers and yard signs are pure advertising.  Conversely, we usually think of a card as conferring some sort of benefit: a membership card, library card, bank card.  Since cards are usually kept in one's wallet, there's no obvious advertising benefit, so it seems reasonable to ask if there is some sort of associated benefit.

Comment: @jamesqf I still fail to see how asking about any fundraising item is valid. If there was any benefit to the card it would be highly advertised in order to raise even more money.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there are no benefits attached to such cards. Giving out cards to donors is a common fundraising tactic for political candidates. “Membership” simply means that you have made a donation and contributed to the campaign.

Together with campaign merchandise, it’s often used to [attract supporters to donate to their campaign](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/25/fashion/presidential-campaign-stores-voter-data.html) and become a “card-carrying member”. Sometimes, these cards are even touted as limited edition to entice supporters to donate.

> Buy an item from a campaign store, and you are not actually purchasing a product; you are making a donation. According to Federal Election Commission regulations, candidates are not allowed to sell items for personal profit, so the product is the “premium” you get in return for your pledge.

To highlight how ubiquitous this tactic is, here are some examples of cards given by political campaigns / organisations:

National Republican Congressional Committee

> [image]

Democratic National Committee

> [image]
>
> Become a card-carrying member of the Democratic Party by making a $7 donation to renew your membership today.

Hillary Clinton’s presidential campaign

In 2016, Clinton’s campaign seized on a comment Trump had made and came up with the “women’s card” which [led to a surge in donations](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/hillary-clinton-donald-trump-woman-card-donors_us_5727b4c5e4b0b49df6ac0b3e) ($2.4m to be exact).

> [image]

Comment: Nothing new under the sun.

Comment: One could wonder what's the point of the magnetic strip on the last card...

Comment: @Fizz Is it even a magnetic strip, or just a black stripe across the bottom?

Answer (score 7):

> Does it entitle the holder to discount rates at one of his hotels?

That would probably be illegal. If someone gives $45 to a PAC, and then a corporation gives that person a $45 discount for their product or services, in effect the corporation is donating $45 to the PAC. Campaign contribution laws have provisions dealing with such straw contributions. Even if the reimbursement is only partial, it's still covered under campaign contribution laws.